# Code style and smells: nested classes

Tags: .net, vb.net

Because of the way I'm working, I'm finding myself nesting classes within classes several levels down and I'm wondering if it could be considered a code smell, and if so, if there might be a better way to design this.

In short, the situation is that I have a `helpers` class in a separate file which contains all kinds of helper methods and helper classes. And in there, the reason I structure things in classes within classes is to make the their usage as verbose and readable as possible, while also keeping things grouped and organized in "levels" and hierarchies, but sometimes I end up with very long usages such as:

`helpers.Calendar.Periods.Semester.startDate`

(That's `class.class.class.class.property`. I just made this one up, but you get the idea.)

Is it 'wrong' to do this? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Not enough for a full answer, but you can [alias an import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type#import-aliases), which can reduce the traversal needed.

Comment: Maybe you can ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are facts and there are opinions.

Fact is, there is a thing called the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (already present here on SO taggged [law-of-demeter](/questions/tagged/law-of-demeter)). According to that yes, it's a code smell.

However, whether you want to follow the advice given there is your decision. It has advantages and disadvantages and weighting them against each other and coming to a conclusion is opinion-based and something we don't do here.

There are related discussions on our sister site, like [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109818/is-code-like-this-a-train-wreck-in-violation-of-law-of-demeter). Asking whether a specific design guideline will help you is maybe better placed there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, with the difference that i am doing something like `namespace.namespace.namespace.namespace.class`.

I don't think it's smelling even if it might be annoying some time.

Moreover ist's structuring putting everything exactly at a place where it is related to. If i want to find the start date of a semester im not looking for something like `helpers.Calendar.semesterStartDate` but i assume the `startDate` is related to the `Semester` instead of the `Calendar` class and really look for `helpers.Calendar.Periods.Semester.startDate`.

Of course everyone has it's own taste for stuff like that but i don't think there is nothing wrong with doing it that way.